# rgl clear specific area of plot

Tags: r, rgl

I have been using `rgl` to plot a block model - using `shade3d` to render the blocks.

I'd like to replace certain blocks using an interactive process. The problem is the rendering is cumulative, so if I overlay a white cube with alpha 0.5 on a blue cube with alpha 1, I'll still see the blue cube. [see below]. I looked at clear3d, but seems to only work at a global level. Any ideas?

```
  shade3d(translate3d(cube3d(),
                      1,
                      1,
                      1),
          col="blue",
          alpha = 1)
```

After some work:

```
  shade3d(translate3d(cube3d(),
                      1,
                      1,
                      1),
          col="white",
          alpha = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clear3d()` removes all objects, as you've discovered. To remove a single object, you want `rgl.pop()`.

As long as you know a given shape's object ID (i.e. its position on the stack of plotted objects), you can use `rgl.pop()` to remove it. The key bookkeeping detail, then, is that you must keep track of the object ID of any object you may later want to remove.

(Conveniently, most **rgl** functions whose *side-effect* is to draw an object to the rgl device return the object ID (or vector of IDs) as their *return value*. Alternatively, use `rgl.ids()` to access the object IDs of all objects plotted on the current device.)

A few more details from `?rgl.pop`:

> ```
> RGL holds two stacks. One is for shapes and the other is for
> lights.  'clear3d' and 'rgl.clear' clear the specified stack, or
> restore the defaults for the bounding box (not visible) or
> viewpoint.  By default with 'id=0' 'rgl.pop' removes the top-most
> (last added) node on the shape stack.  The 'id' argument may be
> used to specify arbitrary item(s) to remove from the specified
> stack.
> ```

So in your case you might do:

```
library(rgl)

ii <- shade3d(translate3d(cube3d(), 1, 1, 1), col="blue", alpha = 1)
shade3d(translate3d(cube3d(), 1, 1, 1), col="white", alpha = 0.5)
rgl.pop(id = ii)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's extremely helpful! I've just joined so I can't vote it up yet, but much appreciated...

Comment: Glad that helped. You're not by any chance implementing Tetris using R and `rgl`, are you ;-)